# Взять из файла данные, поместить их в новый созданный файл

Tags: файлы, powershell

Имеется файл `D:\credits.csv`. В файле лежат данные в формате:

```
number;credit;name
1; 80; Max
2; 160; Denis
3; 27.8; Anna
4; 18; Tom
5;....
```

Нужен скрипт, который выберет строки, в которых значение столбца `credit` больше 2 символов (т.е. третья строка тоже должна быть выбрана, хоть и значение меньше 99), создаст новый файл `D:\names.txt` и поместит туда нужные строки в формате:

```
160, Denis
27.8, Anna
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Csv ./credits.csv  -Delimiter ';' | 
 Foreach-Object {
    if( $_.credit.Length -ge 3 ) {
      Write-Host $_.name $_.credit  
     }
  }
```

`-ge` - больше или равно

```
PS /> cat ./test.csv
number;credit;name
1;80;Max
2;160;Denis
3;27.8;Anna
4;18;Tom
PS /> Import-Csv ./test.csv  -Delimiter ';' | Foreach-Object{ if($_.credit.Length -ge 3 ) {Write-Host $_.name $_.credit  }}
Denis 160
Anna 27.8
PS />
```

p.s. оставил за вами добавление в файл.

Comment: Спасибо! В конечном файле (поменял Write-Host на Write-Output и в конце добавил | Out-File D:\names.txt) информация отображается таким образом, что всё идёт с новой строки
`(1 строка)Denis
(2 строка)160
(3 строка)Anna
(4 строка)27.8`
Как сделать чтобы имя и сумма были в одной строке? и как добавить запятые между именами и суммами?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: запятые добавил через кавычки `$_.name "," $_.credit` , но, запятая тоже идёт в отдельную строку.

Comment: покажите полностью что у вас внутри if-а

Comment: Тут чуть больше: `Foreach-Object {
    if( $_.credit.Length -ge 3 ) {
      Write-Output $_.name "," $_.credit  
     }
  } | Out-File D:\names.txt`

Comment: Вот отдельно только if (поменял порядок на нужный) `{ if( $_.credit.Length -ge 3 ) { Write-Output $_.credit ","  $_.name } }`